# How to use 0ah and 0dh in File handling (Irvine)

Tags: assembly, irvine32

I am doing file handling where I have to take one line from file and modify(encrypt) that data after that I have to replace at that place now the problem is how can I stop my cursor at the end of that line for a moment and after modification I want that cursor at beginning and override the line.

```
mov edx,offset filename
call OpenInputFile
mov fileHandle,eax
;mov eax,0ah
cmp eax,INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE; error opening file?
jne file_ok                 ; no: skip
mWrite <"Invalid File<BAD FILE>",0>
jmp quit                
file_ok:
mov edx,OFFSET buffer
mov ecx,158
call ReadFromFile
mov esi,offset buffer ; source
mov edi, offset pixels ; destination
```

I got clue from some threat that by using 0dh and 0ah you can skip a line and jump your cursor to at beginning but they were working on some string I am trying it on file handling.

like I've file called text.txt:

123
345
234
654
234
745
234
654

First I am trying to skip first 2 lines so I am storing them in some array and then not using them. now the problem is I am taking 234 and doing some modification on it now am trying to replace at it place reason I am doing this because file contain more than 200k values I want few of them so I just want to modify 100 to 200. any help I am surfing for very long time but I couldn't find related file handling.

Comment: You're trying to develop an algorithm.  Suggest you do it in C first, then when its working, translate the C code into assembly.

Comment: how can i convert C to assembly

Comment: I am not asking for any algo i am just asking how can i use 0ah and 0dh

Comment: I didn't say you were asking for an algorithm, from your question I observed that you are trying to develop one.  That kind of thing is easier done in C than in assembly.  You can translate C into assembly using a compiler, or, by hand by translating each line into equivalent assembly.

Comment: 0a and 0d are line feed and carriage return characters. These characters are found at the end of a line.  Take a look at an ASCII chart.

Comment: ik thr working but how am i supposed to use them in file handling.

Comment: When you see one you're at the end of a line.